# Wildcard capture error

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

The classes I am dealing with are as follows,

```
public interface One{
     public Two get();
}

public class Foo{...}
public class Bar extends Foo{...}

public abstract class Parent<T extends Foo> implements One {...}

public abstract class Child<T extends Foo> extends Parent<T>
```

I have a static method that will return a Child object given a Foo object,

```
public static Child<? extends Foo> get(Foo f){...}
```

This method returns a child constructed from either a Foo or Bar object. The code that throws the error is this,

```
Foo f = new Foo();
Child<? extends Foo> child = O.get(f);
Two t = S.apply(child);
```

The apply method,

```
public Two apply(One o){...};
```

The error that gets thrown is,

```
apply(One) in S cannot be applied to (Child<capture#123 of ?>)
```

My current workaround for this problem is to change the code to this,

```
Foo f = new Foo();
Child<? extends Foo> child = O.get(f);
Object o = child;
One one = (One)o;
Two t = S.apply(one);
```

This resolves the error, I have no idea why the explicit cast to object needs to be there, but there it is.

**Can anyone tell me if it is possible to modify the code so the casts are not necessary to get this to work?**

Comment: The code you have given works for me without the given workaround when compiled for both 1.5 and 1.6. It's almost as if Child does not know that Parent implements One.

Comment: Yeah, I would clean and rebuild.  Or if you're not giving us an example that exhibits the problem, give us an example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: It is the nightly build that throws the error, so I am not quite sure what the exact compiler settings are. I am trying to get a way to better reproduce it now.

Comment: Also did you compile it through an IDE or with javac? Eclipse is saying all is good, however when I do it through ant it throws the error.

Comment: @ILMTitan how could you compile this? Am I missing anything? What is `Two` here? is it an interface or class. `Two t = S.apply(one);` again what is `S` here?

Comment: The implementations of Two and S dont mater with regards to the problem, S is just the nme of the class where the static method apply() is defined, Two is an arbitrary object that gets returned from any class implementing the interface One

Answer (score 0):

I think I can tell you. Unfortunately, you are missing a lot of code, but I have seen this kind of thing before and know how to tackle it. Solving it involves a not often seen syntax of java.

Firstly, you have to type your static method, like this:

```
public static <T extends Foo> Child<T> get(Foo f){...}
```

Although not having seen the code, it is possible that given that change, that this will work:

```
Two t = S.apply(child);
```

However, if you need to, you can provide the type if you need to, like this:

```
Two t = S.<Two>apply(child); // Cool huh?
```

This syntax is how you coerce the type for a typed static method.

I'm not sure if this exact code will work for you, because you haven't provided enough code, but the solution will be pretty close to this if not this.

If this doesn't work, post *all* of the relevant code you have and I'll try to make it work for you.

Comment: This static `get` method does not have the same meaning as the original one. Here the caller can decide what is the parameter type, while with `Child<? extends Foo>` the method itself can decide it.  I think one actually wants `public static <T extends Foo> Child<T> get(T f){...}`.

Comment: Also, the `apply` method seems to be non-generic, you can't provide a type parameter here.

Comment: If you go back and read my post, yo'll see this approach requires two steps - the first is to parameterize the method - see step 1. of my answer

Comment: There are two methods here - one is the apply method, the other is the `get` method. If I understand right, you added a type parameter to `get` (and then not used it as the parameter type), but did not change `apply`. (But of course you are right with the last sentence: without all of the code we can't really do anything here.)

Comment: @Paŭlo What more code do you need? There is a lot of it and I tired to include just the relevant snippets.

Comment: For example, a complete example (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) would be helpful.